# SIM800L microphone problem

Tags: microphone, gsm, sim900, sim

I want to feed SIM800L a microphone signal.

I found this page in the datasheet and it worked but I need more a sensitive microphone. I want to hear voices in room as much as possible, like a spy bug.
The SIM800L microphone input is designed for millivolt level signaly so I have problem with amplifier audio in.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: The module is designed to power the microphone directly. If you want to add a preamplifier, you'll have to power the microphone yourself. There are many examples on the web of how to do that.

Comment: Can i use common emiter amplifier ? If yes ,What is suitable Av of circuit ?

Comment: Well, what's the difference between the level you're getting now and the level you want? This may require some experimentation.